# How do you detect when a JFace Dialog (or other modal component) has been opened in an Eclipse RAP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, jface, eclipse-rap

In my Eclipse RAP application, I need to have a component change the way it looks whenever any other component opens a dialog box (or any other element in the foreground). How do I have my component detect when this happens? I have tried using Display.addListener/addFilter, but those do not get events when JFace Dialogs open up.

[As an aside, the reason for this is that this component contains a Java applet, and Java applets do not obey z-ordering, so the applet appears on top of the foreground dialog box.]

Answer (score 2):

If you add a display filter for the `SWT.Activate` event, you should be notified for every shell that becomes active, including JFace dialogs. This works for me with RAP 2.0 M3, but should also work with earlier versions.

```
display.addFilter( SWT.Activate, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    System.out.println( display.getActiveShell() );
  }
} );
```